# How to predict with cv.glm in R

Tags: r, glm, prediction

Suppose I have the dataset:

```
mydata=data.frame(
  status = as.factor(c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)),
  a = c(1,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5),
  b = c(4,2,3,6,2,1,3,4,5,6)
)
```

I construct a glm model, train it on half of the observations, and use that model to predict the response of the other half of the observations.

```
   train=sample(1:nrow(mydata), nrow(mydata)/2)
   test=mydata[-train,]
   test.response=status[-train]
   fit=glm(status~., data=mydata, family="binomial", subset=train)
   probs=predict(fit, test, type="response")
   pred=rep(0,5)
   pred[probs>0.5]=1
   table(pred, test.response)
```

And this tells me how many true positives and true negatives I have predicted (I had 2, and 2, respectively).

```
     test.response
pred 0 1
   0 2 0
   1 1 2
```

Instead of manually coding the train and test datasets, I turne to `cv.glm` so that R can just cross-validate for me.

```
   library(boot)
   fit2=glm(status~., data=mydata, family="binomial")
   cv.fit=cv.glm(mydata, fit2, K=2)
```

My question is, how can I use the cross validated model to predict my response variable? What I used before was `probs=predict(fit, test, type="response")`, but in this case I don't know what `test` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
require(boot)
require(glmnet)
status <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
ymat   <- as.matrix(status)
xdata  <- data.frame(a,b)
xmat   <- as.matrix(xdata)
fit.cv <- cv.glmnet(y = ymat, x = xmat, family="binomial")
lmin   <- fit.cv$lambda.min
l1se   <- fit.cv$lambda.1se
net    <- glmnet(y = ymat, x = xmat, family="binomial")
predict(net, s=lmin, type = "nonzero")
colnames(status)[predict(net, s=lmin,type="nonzero")$X1]
plot(cv.glmnet(y = ymat,x = xmat, family= "binomial", type = "class"))
plot(cv.glmnet(y = ymat,x = xmat, family= "binomial", type = "mae"))
plot(cv.glmnet(y = ymat,x = xmat, family= "binomial", type = "deviance"))
plot(cv.glmnet(y = ymat,x = xmat, family= "binomial", type = "mse"))
plot(cv.glmnet(y = ymat,x = xmat, family= "binomial", type = "auc")) #needs more data
```

The dataset was really tiny so I recommend trying this on a bigger dataset to avoid warnings/errors.

Comment: Why cv.glmnet rather than cv.glm (as OP requested)?

Comment: OP didn't specifically request that function and was satisfied with this solution. There was probably a technical reason but it's been a year so I don't remember.

Comment: Is there any step in this code that performs the bootstrapping in the OP code?

Comment: @Arthur There is no bootstrapping in the question, the author just used the `boot` library to attempt crossvalidation. There's no bootstrapping in the sense of resampling with replacement to generate new datasets.